# Springboot: join query two Mysql DB schemas

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot app with 2 datasources configured for 2 schemas in the same MySQL DB instance. I'm able to query both datasources separately but the question is: how can I query both of them in one transaction?

Something similar to this SQL:

```
select a.systemid, c.name from (select systemid from DATATABLE.PROPERTY group by systemid having date_add(max(lastfound), INTERVAL 4 DAY) < CURDATE()) a
                     inner join DATATABLE.SYSTEM b on a.systemid = b.id
                     inner join CONFTABLE.SYSTEMS c on c.name = b.name;
```

(this query works from IntelliJ database console).
How can I achieve the same results within Spring application?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that it's enough to specify the data source as

> jdbc:mysql://database-01:3306/

na use JdbcTemplate with SCHEMA.TABLE query. 
Works like a charm.